# Are "target" and "receiver" synonyms in the ES2015 specification?

Tags: javascript

Both "receiver" and "target" are used in the ES2015 spec (see examples below) and elsewhere on the Web, to refer to the object used as the `this` value.

Are these words synonyms or do they have subtly different meanings?

Is there a single correct term to refer to the `this` value of a function at invocation time?

I note that the signature of `Reflect.get` in [26.1.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reflect.get) uses both terms indicating a difference of meaning.

This question stems from a perceived inconsistency of nomenclature in the ES2015 spec.

**Spec Usage Examples:**

Table 5, row 7 (`[[Get]]`), section [6.1.7.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) (my emboldening):

> Return the value of the property whose key is propertyKey from this
>   object. If any ECMAScript code must be executed to retrieve the
>   property value, **Receiver** is used as the this value when evaluating the
>   code.

Paragraph 2, section [6.1.7.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) (my emboldening):

> Internal method names are polymorphic. This means that different
>   object values may perform different algorithms when a common internal
>   method name is invoked upon them. That actual object upon which an
>   internal method is invoked is the “**target**” of the invocation. If, at
>   runtime, the implementation of an algorithm attempts to use an
>   internal method of an object that the object does not support, a
>   TypeError exception is thrown.

Comment: You may want to post some example code to clarify your question.

Comment: you started halfway down the train'o'thought. could we start back at the station?

Comment: Can you include link to specific portion of specification that you are referring to at Question?

Comment: If you were paying attention to your question in the first 10-15 minutes after you posted it, you could have clarified it before it was closed.  With 12k of rep, I would have though you would have known that.

Comment: Sorry, neglected to follow up the question fast enough.

Answer (score 9):

To recap:

- Every call to the internal method of an object has a "target", the object which the call is made on.
- "Receiver" is the 2<sup>nd</sup> parameter of the `[[Get]]` method, and the 3<sup>rd</sup> of the `[[Set]]` method.
- Other [internal object methods](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) don't have this extra parameter.

Then, why does `[[Get]]` and `[[Set]]` have Receiver?
Because it is *not* target.

**Receiver is used to call getter and setter in the scope of [[Get]] / [[Set]].**

ES6 [9.1.8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-get-p-receiver):

1. You call `A.Get( 'property', A )`
2. If A does not have 'property', `A.prototype.Get( 'property', A )` is called.

   3. Target is now "A.prototype".  But Receiver remains "A".
   4. If A.prototype has a getter function for 'property', it will be called with Receiver A, instead of the target A.prototype.

> Note that ES5's [[Get]] (8.12.3) do the same in a different way and without Receiver, partially because prototype climbing happens in another part (8.12.2).

Receiver only exist in the context of [[Get]] and [[Set]], and serves a different purpose than target.

- When [[Get]] need to refer its target, it use O.
  O is different for each recursive call of [[Get]] as it climbs the prototype chain.
- Receiver remains the same as [[Get]] climbs the prototype chain.
  Its *value* is passed to getter as a parameter, and what happens next is no longer in the same scope as Receiver.

> O and Receiver *may* refer to the same object, but that doesn't matter in the context of [[Get]] or [[Set]].
>   In fact, [Reflect.get](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reflect.get) allows the caller to set a different target and Receiver and make them different from the get go.

For other internal object methods, most of them do not climb the prototype chain at all.  The two that do ([`[[HasProperty]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-hasproperty-p) and [`[[Enumerate]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-enumerate)), don't need to preserve the initial target (so to speak).

---

With that settled, you [then ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644517/are-target-and-receiver-synonyms-in-the-es2015-specification/37653947#comment62830744_37653947) whether the spec gives "Receiver" a meaning to be used in general JavaScript discussion, like how it defines "target" in 6.1.7.2.
This answer is no.

1. "Receiver" has a very narrow scope, used only as parameter name, but "target" is used there in a general, less formal way.
2. "target" is a term borrowed from general discussions -
   ES5 doesn't define the concept of target of invocation.
   ES5 "target" can be a parameter, variable, statement, expression, or the called function. But not an implicit replacement for `this`.
3. The spec is written to convey "JavaScript behaviour" in very, very precise terms, making it very technical including the use of parameter.
   It simply serves a different communication than general programming discussions.

   3.a. Many JS developer don't read the spec at all.
      It is unnecessary for everyday coding.

   3.b. We talk about "closure", "scope chains", "event queue", and "fat arrow" or "lambda", do we not?
   The spec defined none of these terms.

   3.c.
   The spec may name things differently, as in Execution Context or Job Queue.
   It may simply not name things. Closure is an emergent behaviour.
   And when it does name, it does not create alias.  Arrow Function is never called lambda.

**The spec does not regulate general discussions. 

Use common sense for common discussions.**

Comment: Thank you for writing this answer, but I do not think your steps 1,2,3,4 are correct. When following the prototype chain the target does not change. I will await further responses.

Comment: @BenAston Look at 9.1.8 step 4d.  It calls `parent.[[Get]](P, Receiver)` - parent is the target of this recursive call, not O.

Comment: So the `Receiver` parameter is some kind of `target` override to maintain expected behavior?

Comment: @BenAston Since Receiver only exists in [[Get]], you can compare them only *in the scope* of [[Get]].  They are the same on first call but the spec *does not concern* that in the context of [[Get]].  In [[Get]], O is O and Receiver is Receiver.  And `Receiver` is not *technically* overriding `this`, unlike ES5 8.12.3 step 13.  In ES6, `this` of [[Call]] (9.2.1) is a parameter, different from target (`F`). There is no "default" `this` to override.  If you are still confused, please consider open a more specific question or come chat in the JS room.

Comment: I understand the need for "receiver" in this case, but my question is: is the word "receiver" something that has a well-defined meaning outside of the narrow context of specific internal methods defined in the spec? For example; if I use the term "target of a function" in a general JS discussion people will know exactly what I mean. Does "receiver" have a corresponding well-defined precise meaning in a more general setting?

Comment: @BenAston We search through the spec on the day this question is reopened, no? Did you find many usage of "receiver" outside of these narrow contexts? What make you think the spec defines the terms people use in general discussions? Can you find "closure" or "scope chain" or "fat arrow" or "lambda" or "browser object" or "event queue" in the spec? You think you can just go generally talk about "Object Environment Record", "Code Realms", or "Job"?  Your English is good, your skill is good, so please use your common sense in common discussions.

Comment: You say "ES 5 doesn't have the concept of target of invocation." and yet the term is littered throughout the ES5 spec. What do you mean by this?

Comment: @BenAston Please read it carefully and think before you ask, and provide supports for your questions. In ES 5.0 (2009) the term "target" is used as parameter name and as variable name - which is just a name, need to be explicitly assigned, and can be anything.  When it is not a name, it commonly refers to target *statement/expression/function*.  The "target of invocation", undefined in ES5, would means the function being called, not the target object you are thinking after reading ES6.

Answer (score 1):

This probably does not answer the question. But here goes..

The term *receiver* derives from OOP design where everything is abstracted as objects. Execution of a program consists mainly of communication between objects. Object communicate with each other by *invoking* each other's methods. Thus the object being invoked upon is *receiving* a message. Hence the term.

The syntax, however, has extended to languages/contexts where there are, in a sense, "objects" but not exactly OOP. Many languages pick up the convenience of being able to invoke a function/method via some object/scope using the syntax `some_object.some_method()` and still refer to `some_object` as being the receiver. Usually referred to as `this` or `self` or just first parameter or a combination thereof in the function/method definition. JavaScript takes this a step further and allows dynamic binding of `this`. While in fact the object being called upon is not receiving anything and the syntax is just sugar for implicitly using the object as one of the arguments to the function being invoked.